# WebSocket problem with Apache and Wildfly

Tags: java, spring, apache, websocket, wildfly

When i deploy my spring application i get this problem with websocket

```
  Forwarding to error page from request [/active-users] due to exception [Servlet request failed to upgrade to WebSocket: https://remote-host/test/active-users; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000077: The underlying transport does not support HTTP upgrade]
```

I currently using Apache 2.2 and wildfly 18 (i can't update them)

in my wildfly i have this configuration for websocket:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:10.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="true">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp" record-request-start-time="true" redirect-socket="http"/>
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" record-request-start-time="true" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" record-request-start-time="true" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
        </subsystem>
```

In my spring application i have this 2 classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ActiveUsersWebSocketHandler activeUsersWebSocketHandler;

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler defaultSockJsTaskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(activeUsersWebSocketHandler, "/active-users")
           .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
```

and:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class ActiveUsersWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private Set<WebSocketSession> activeSessions = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        log.info("{}.{} ", this.getClass().getName(), "afterConnectionEstablished");
        activeSessions.add(session);
        sendActiveUsersCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        log.info("{}.{} ", this.getClass().getName(), "afterConnectionClosed");
        activeSessions.remove(session);
        sendActiveUsersCount();
    }

    private void sendActiveUsersCount() {
        log.info("{}.{} sending users count", this.getClass().getName(), "sendActiveUsersCount");
        Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();
        payload.put("activeUsersCount", activeSessions.size());

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonPayload;
        try {
            jsonPayload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("{}.{} error: {}", this.getClass().getName(), "sendActiveUsersCount", e.getMessage());
            throw new CustomException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error", e.getMessage());
        }

        for (WebSocketSession session : activeSessions) {
            try {
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(jsonPayload));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("{}.{} error while sending message: {}", this.getClass().getName(), "sendActiveUsersCount", e.getMessage());
                throw new CustomException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you suggest me anything i can fix the error without update apache to 2.4 also this are my apache config:

```
80:
# WebSocket proxy
ProxyPass /ws/ ws://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://localhost:8009/test

# WebSocket Secure proxy
ProxyPass /wss/ wss://localhost:8009/nnn
ProxyPassReverse /wss/ wss://localhost:8009/test
443:
# WebSocket proxy
ProxyPass /ws/ ws://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://localhost:8009/test

# WebSocket Secure proxy
ProxyPass /wss/ wss://localhost:8009/test
ProxyPassReverse /wss/ wss://localhost:8009/test
```